# How to find the max and min for the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{e^{2x}-2e^x\cos y +1}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I was trying to find the max and min for the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{e^{2x}-2e^x\cos y +1}$ subjected to the condition $x^2+y^2=1$. Some computation shows that $f_x=\frac{e^x(e^x-\cos y)}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-2e^x\cos y +1}}$ and $f_y=\frac{e^x\sin y}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-2e^x\cos y +1}}$. Hence the question reduces to solving the simultaneous equations
$f_x=0$
$f_y=0$
$x^2+y^2=1$
which is equivalent to 
$e^x-\cos y=0$
$e^x\sin y=0$
$x^2+y^2=1$
which has no solution. But the constraint set $\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2=1\}$ is compact, and hence extremum should exist.

Comment: Solving the system $f_x=0$, $f_y=0$ to find maximum or minimum only makes sense **without** the restriction $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: You may use the fact that $f(x,y)=|1-e^{x+iy}|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define: $g(x,y)=e^{2x}-2e^{x}cos(y)+1$. You can convince yourself that $g(x,y)\geq 0$ $\forall(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Since on non negative real numbers the quadratic function is monotonic, we can minimize/maximize the function $g$ (which is easier to work with) instead of $f$.

By Lagrange Multiplier Theorem we have to find the stationary points of $$L(x,y,\lambda)=g(x,y)-\lambda\cdot h(x,y),$$ where $h(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}-1$.

So we end up with the system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
L_{x}=2e^{x}(e^{x}-cos(y))-2\lambda x=0\\
L_{y}=2e^{x}sin(y)-2\lambda y=0\\ 
L_{\lambda}=x^{2}+y^{2}-1=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Let's consider some different cases.

$(1)$ The condition $y=0$ satisfies the second equation. From the third we find that $x=\pm1.$ Hence the stationary points of $L(x,y,\lambda)$ are: $(-1,0,-e^{-1}(e^{-1}-1))$ and $(1,0,e(e-1))$.

$(2)$ Suppose now that $y\neq 0$. From the second equation we get $\lambda=e^{x}\frac{sin(y)}{y}$. Substituting in the first we end up with: $$e^{x}(e^{x}-cos(y))-e^{x}\frac{x}{y}sin(y)=0 \Leftrightarrow e^{x}-cos(y)-\frac{x}{y}sin(y)=0.$$ The constrain tells us that $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and the fact that $y\neq 0$ implies that $x\neq \pm 1$. We want to find the zeros of the function $\theta(x,y)=e^{x}-cos(y)-\frac{x}{y}sin(y)$. Substituting $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ gives us a new function: $$\rho(x)=\theta(x,y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})=e^{x}-cos(\sqrt{1-x^2})-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}sin(\sqrt{1-x^2}),$$
with $x\in(-1,1)$.

The function $\rho(x)$ is strictly increasing (check it out) and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-1}\rho(x)=e^{-1}> 0$. So $\theta(x,y)$ has no zeros on the constrain $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ with $y\neq0$.

Therefore from $(1)$ we get these two constrained extrema for $g$: $P_{1}=(-1,0)$ and $P_{2}=(1,0)$.

$f(P_{1})=\sqrt{g(P_{1})}=\sqrt{(e^{-1}-1)^2}=|e^{-1}-1|=1-e^{-1}$, and $f(P_{2})=\sqrt{g(P_{2})}=\sqrt{(e-1)^2}=e-1$.

So $P_{1}$ is the minimum of $f$ with the restriction $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and $P_{2}$ is the maximum of $f$ with the same restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the graphical solution:

[image]

Hence, $f(-1,0)=\sqrt{e^{-2}-2e^{-1}+1}\approx 0.63$ (min) and $f(1,0)=\sqrt{e^2-2e+1}\approx 1.72$ (max)

Wolframalpha [agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimize%20%5Csqrt%7Be%5E%7B2x%7D-2e%5Ex%5Ccos%20y%20%2B1%7D%20s.t.%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1).